# Mysql query select row id that is not in the other table

Tags: php, mysql, row, field

I have to tables 'config_questions' and 'user_question'.

'config_questions' fields:

- question_id
- question_text

'user_question' fields

- question_id
- user_id

The mysql result (question_text field) has to be one question from 'config_questions'table where the question_id and the user_id isn't in the 'user_question' table.

Where do I start? How can I manage this in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're looking for a new question for a given user, so you only want one question to come back.

```
select min( question_text) from config_questions
 where question_id not in (select question_id 
                             from user_question 
                            where user_id = 1);
```

will do it for user_id = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use not in

```
 select question_text  from config_questions 
 where question_id not in (select question_id from user_question);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT question_id, question_text 
FROM config_questions
WHERE question_id NOT IN (
    SELECT question_id 
    FROM user_question)
```

to start a sub-selection giving you all question_ids from user_questions and only select those questions which dont have one of them (NOT IN returns only the results which don't match with the following pattern).

If you really want only one result you can use 
    SELECT TOP 1 question_id, question_text

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.